Stability of Euler discretization
I am looking at the discretization of an ODE:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n + \alpha f(x_n),$$
where $x_n\in R^d$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable and such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)$ is Hurwitz (i.e., the real part of all of its eigenvalues are negative).
I want to claim that $0$ is exponentially stable, in the sense that there exist a neighborhood $N$ of $0$ and some $\alpha_0$ such that if $x_0\in N$ and $\alpha\le\alpha_0$:
$$ \| x_n \| \le a e^{-b \alpha n}\|x_0\|, $$
for some $a,b>0$.
I think that I know how to prove it by setting $\alpha_0$ such that the modulus of all the eigenvalues of $I+\alpha f'(0)$ are smaller than $1$, but to me this looks like a known result. Yet, I am unable to find a reference. Would anyone have an idea of where to find a statement for such a claim?

Did you miss the condition that $f(0)=0$?

Indeed, $f(0)=0$ ! Thanks for pointing out the typo.

This is known as Grobman-Hartman theorem, see, for example Arnold, Geometrical methods in the theory of ordinary differential equations, Chap. 3, sect. 14, subsection 3.
